# Does jquery-tmpl super else if statement?

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

Does [jQuery tmpl](http://skilldrick.co.uk/tmpl/#slide1) support the "else if" condition? wondering why not. Can't find it in any documentation.

Comment: Thx - didn't know about handlebars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that it lacks the syntax of `else if` but generally speaking the `else if` is not really a new command, it an `else` followed by another `if`.

So practically you are stuck with the following approach:

```
//data:
var data = { name: 'Dave', important: false, flag: true };

<!--template:-->
{{if important}}
    <p>It's our most valued customer, ${name}!</p>
{{else}}
    <p>Hi there ${name}.</p>
    {{if flag}}
        <p>It's a flagged customer, ${name}!</p>
    {{else}}
        <p>Hi there ${name}.</p>
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Yes, if you have a big list of want to implement a complex scenario the template code will be hard to read and change and fix... :(

Comment: FYI jQuery Templates are being superseded by JsRender - which does have   an else if feature: {{if pathOrExpr1}}...{{else pathOrExpr2}}...{{else}}...{{/if} - see: http://www.jsviews.com/#iftag